# meteor: Iterating over a collection by field value

Tags: meteor

I have items with a category field and name field, e.g.:

```
{ category: 'CategoryOne', name: "ItemOne" },
{ category: 'CategoryOne', name: "ItemTwo" },
{ category: 'CategoryTwo', name: "ItemThree" },
... etc
```

What I would like to do is display these under a heading for the category.

I am new to meteor, and having quite the time doing two things:

(1)  Getting a reactive list of categories, or
(2)  Iterating through the items, displaying them grouped by category.

I'm not sure what is the correct Meteor approach here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately minimongo doesn't have support for aggregation yet so this is a bit difficult. The following is how I would approach it.

First create 2 template helpers. The first just puts together a list of the categories and returns an array of category names, The second takes the category name as a parameter and returns a cursor of all of the records in that category.

```
Template.categories.helpers({
    categories: function(){
        var added = [];
        return Items.find().map(function (item) {
            if(_(added).indexOf(item.category) === -1){
                return item.category;
            }
        });
    },
    categoryItems: function(category){
        return Items.find({category:category});
    }
});
```

Next the template needs nested {{#each}} blocks with the first one iterating over the categories array and passing the category names to the next each as the parameter of the next helper.

```
<template name="categories">
    {{#each categories}}
        <h1>{{this}}</h1>
        <ul>
        {{#each items this}}
            <li>{{name}}</li>
        {{/each}}
        </ul>
    {{/each}}
</template>
```

Comment: I translated this into Coffeescript, and it is indeed a workable solution. I had a little trouble with the if statement working, so I just built an array using map() and called _.uniq() on the result.  I also changes the find() call there to sort by category, so uniq() can be get the hint that it's sorted.